# Resources for a modern looking Vaadin UI

Tags: java, gwt, user-interface, vaadin

I'm new in Vaadin development. In my view, gwt looks a bit old and not very "web'ish".
Do you know some good resources which helps me to create a nice looking Vaadin UI?

Vaadin provides a good looking demo application on it's [Github account](https://github.com/vaadin). But it's hard for me to "learn from code".

Thanks for you help!

Regards, 
- Tobo

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use this: https://vaadin.com/wiki and this: https://vaadin.com/tutorial and this: https://vaadin.com/features?

Comment: Hi,because I did it already. :) I'm looking for a more "designer" point of view instead of a coder's one.

Answer (score 0):

there is a couple of themes at https://vaadin.com/directory#browse/type/2 http://demo.vaadin.com/RunoTheme http://demo.vaadin.com/chameleon-editor http://demo.vaadin.com/ReindeerTheme

and in my experience it's pretty easy to create a custom one (e.g. https://saudibuypal.com )

and here is a guide about creating it https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.creating.html

Comment: Hi Oleg,you are right. But if you change the 'target version' to the current version 7. There will be no themes available. I'll have a look at your given link. Thanks!